# Sass extend and parent selector

Tags: css, sass

I have the following Sass placeholder and I want to extend it.

```
%btn
  // ...button styling...
  &[disabled], &.btn--disabled
    color: red

.btn-primary
  @extend %btn
```

The CSS output is the following:

```
 [disabled].btn-primary, .btn--disabled.btn-primary{ color: red; }
```

When I'd like to get the following:

```
 .btn-primary[disabled], .btn-primary.btn--disabled { color: red; }
```

I don't get why the output order is not the same as the specified one. How can I change that?

Comment: If the selector is valid, does it matter what order it is in?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're after is the following:

```
%btn[disabled], %btn.btn--disabled
    color: red

.btn-primary
    @extend %btn
```

To help conceptualize what the structure will be for the CSS that's generated, just remember that `%placeholder` is a token that's going to be substituted with the selector that's `@extend`ing it.

**Edit**

Actually, this still outputs

```
[disabled].btn-primary, .btn--disabled.btn-primary {
    color: red; }
```

which I wouldn't expect... Syntactically, `[disabled].btn-primary` is the same as `.btn-primary[disabled]`, but it's annoying that the source ordering isn't being respected.

Here's a bug report I found that describes this behaviour (apparently, it's just how `@extend` works):

- [placeholder-selectors decide on the actual selector's order, not the actual selectors](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/682)

Comment: Thanks, but the output is exactly the same.