# More flexible placeholder selector usage

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

Given a placeholder selector as

```
%theme
    .red
        :color red
        :background-color blue

    .yellow
        :color yellow
        :background-color green
```

I'd now like to go ahead and compile it to css such as

```
#content.special_page .red h2, #content.special_page .red .items li { ... }
#content.special_page .yellow h2, #content.special_page .yellow .items li { ... }
```

But this appears not to be possible ...

```
#content.special_page h2
    @extend %theme
```

... will render to ...

```
#content.special_page h2 .red { ... }
#content.special_page h2 .yellow { ... }
```

... and the placeholder selector does not allow me to pass any arguments or a content.

So are there any sass features to solve this, or even some tricky css selectors?

Comment: It is, however, how your problem is solved.

Comment: But both proposed solutions (mixin or the import technique) don't make use of SASS' elegant selector chaining when using `@extend`. So what I  will end up with is repetitive CSS code and this is not what I'm looking for. Or am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 0):

As I discovered while answering a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763171/sass-extend-and-parent-selector/18763386#18763386), the behaviour you're witnessing is apparently [how `@extend` normally works](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/682).